# My Macros stopped working?

Tags: vb.net, macros, ide, visual-studio-2005

For some reason the macros I use in my `VB.net` `IDE` (VS 2005) stopped working. I wrote them myself and used them for a couple of years before they quit working. I have never had a problem before this. I've been trying to find a solution for a few months now. I have tried repairing and re-installing all the service packs and patches for Vista.

I have tried including my macro folder in the add-in paths, but when I do, the options window locks up and I have to use the task manager to close the `devenv.exe`.

This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue caused by a recent Windows update. See [Visual Studio 2010 Macros Stop Working after February 2014 Windows Update](http://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2014/02/13/visual-studio-2010-macros-stop-working-after-february-2014-windows-update/) for solutions how to fix it.

Comment: To be honest, I looked for some kind of security issue that could cause this. Just before I read your post I had already started re-installing Vista on my dev machine, but I'm sure I'll be back to check to solution again once I've re-installed everything. Thanks.