# Visual Studio 2008 always asks if I want to save macros on close

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, macros

The title says it (mostly) all. For the last several weeks, whenever I close Visual Studio 2008, it keeps asking me if I want to save my macro files, obviously even if I haven't touched them. So if I only open VS2008 and then close it (without opening files, or anything) I get this screen:

[image: Do you want so save the following elements?]

It doesn't matter if I select Yes or No, the next time it asks me again.

Any ideas where I can start looking into this problem?

Comment: Timing coincides with the infamous February 2014 Windows update. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413278/my-macros-stopped-working

Comment: Wow, thanks! It worked like a charm! Write it as an answer and I'll accept it.